# Sampling from Truncated Normal

Tags: bayesian, sampling, truncated-normal-distribution

I am trying to sample from a truncated normal using the standard probability integral transform as described on wikipedia with
$$ x = \Phi^{-1} ( \Phi(\alpha) + U*( \Phi(\beta) - \Phi(\alpha)))*\sigma + \mu $$ with $U \sim Uniform(0,1)$, $\alpha = (a-\mu)/\sigma$ and $\beta = (b-\mu)/\sigma$. In my application, $a = 0.0$ and $b = \infty$.
 However, this method fails for instance if $\mu = -0.4$ and $\sigma = 0.05$. I know that sampling positive values with these parameters is highly unlikely. Therefore, I guess I run into errors caused by numerical overflow. I use the GSL library in C to sample the values.
Can you recommend any routine to sample values nevertheless? The PIT yields for instance $\infty$ as sample, which I can obviously not process.
This one I already used:
[Truncated Normal by John Burkardt](https://people.sc.fsu.edu/~jburkardt/presentations/truncated_normal.pdf)

Comment: Sorry, I totally forgot about that post. My bad! I guess I will try the accept-reject method then. I was silently hoping that there exists some kind of library already. For some reason I cannot compile the one by Chopin.

Comment: "Highly unlikely" is somewhat of an understatement; you are trying to sample from a part of the distribution 8 standard deviations from the mean.  Even with double precision, to 15 decimal places that probability rounds off to 0.000000000000001.  If you draw a million samples a second from a Normal distribution, it would take you about 30 years before you had a 50% chance of drawing one that far (or more) from the mean.

Comment: Wow, tbh I didn't consider it that way :D I am using the truncated normal as a posterior distribution, which requires a value larger than 0. Would you say it's reasonable to set it equal to the lower boundary (which is 0) in cases where the sampling method fails?

Comment: @Tim Actually I don't think a generalized extreme value distribution is relevant here.

Comment: @Glen_b you are right. Unfortunately, I can't edit my comment so I deleted it. What I meant to say is that in case of such extreme tails we would rather use extreme value theory in modeling them rather then looking at the ordinary tails.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you're sampling the extreme tail, a version of the accept reject method X'ian describes in the paper linked in his answer at that earlier question (basically using an exponential proposal) should work really well.

[The comment containing the link was deleted. I mean [this earlier Q](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/226662/truncated-normal-distribution-theoretical-mean-outside-truncation-boundaries)]

[image: Plot of upper tail of normal with exponential majorizing function]

Out this far, the rejection rate should only be about 2.5%; that's pretty decent; you would be generating about 41 exponentials for every 40 truncated normal values you keep.

Comment: Thank you for the illustration! I kind of solved the problem with the negative mean. In a previous publication, the authors decided to block two variables together which led to complicated expressions for the mean. I "unblocked" these variables and get perfectly behaving means now. But thanks to you all for your helpful comments!