# random number generation of truncated multivariate normal distribution

Tags: random-variable, random-generation, truncated-normal-distribution, truncated-distributions

I want to generate random numbers from truncated multivariate normal distribution specified as follows:

$ \begin{bmatrix}
Y \\
X
\end{bmatrix} \sim N
\begin{pmatrix}
\begin{bmatrix}
\mu_Y \\
\mu_X
\end{bmatrix},  \begin{bmatrix}
\sigma_{11} & \sigma_{12} \\
\sigma_{12} & \sigma_{22}
\end{bmatrix}
\end{pmatrix}
 $ where $-1<Y<1$ and $0< X < 1$.

I have tried R command "rtmvnorm". By looking at the generated numbers, they seem to satisfy $-1<Y<1$ and $0<X < 1$ and their means are close to the theoretical values. However, checking the variances and covariance, they are much smaller than the theoretical values. Below is the code and output.

```
library(TruncatedNormal)
n <- 500000
mu <- c(0, 0.5)
sigma <- matrix(c(1, 0.3, 0.3, 1), 2,2)

lb <- c(-1, 0)
ub <- c( 1, 1)
X <- rtmvnorm(n, mu, sigma, lb, ub)
head(X,10)
colMeans(X)
cov(X)
```

Output is as follows:

```
> head(X,10)
             [,1]       [,2]
 [1,]  0.25065762 0.86349926
 [2,] -0.60200807 0.28179668
 [3,]  0.07264893 0.03382819
 [4,]  0.48001486 0.83693168
 [5,]  0.19537872 0.34182959
 [6,]  0.11081347 0.96187636
 [7,]  0.98743046 0.85316679
 [8,] -0.92329383 0.52252609
 [9,]  0.10285388 0.33629839
[10,] -0.31047567 0.75213528
> colMeans(X)
[1] -0.0008484419  0.5002994220
> cov(X)
            [,1]        [,2]
[1,] 0.287918806 0.007407156
[2,] 0.007407156 0.080514144
```

I'm wondering if it is possible to adjust so that empirical (co)variances are close to the theoretical value.

Comment: Are you comparing with the covariance of the untruncated Normal or with the covariance of the truncated Normal? They are not the same.

Comment: The parameters of the truncated distribution regard the parameters of the distribution *before* the truncation, see e.g. https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/226662/truncated-normal-distribution-theoretical-mean-outside-truncation-boundaries/226666#226666 , this is "by design".

Comment: In other words, when you enter `mu` and `sigma` in the code, they are _not_ the mean and covariance of the simulated random variable.

Comment: Related: https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/157963.  (The truncation there is radial rather than Cartesian.)

Answer (score 11):

In general, $\begin{bmatrix}
\mu_Y \\
\mu_X
\end{bmatrix}$ and
$\begin{bmatrix}
\sigma_{11} & \sigma_{12} \\
\sigma_{12} & \sigma_{22}
\end{bmatrix}$
are *not* the expectation and covariance matrix of your truncated bivariate normal distribution.

One way to calculate these is given by [Manjunath and Wilhelm (2021)](https://jbds.isdsa.org/public/journals/1/html/v1n1/p2/) and implemented in the `mtmvnorm` function of the `tmvtnorm` package by the same authors.

They derived the expected value and covariance matrix of a truncated $d$–variate normal random variable $\mathbf X = \left(X_1, \ldots, X_d\right)^\top$, component-wise truncated from below at $\mathbf a = \left(a_1, \ldots, a_d\right)^\top$ and from above at $\mathbf b = \left(b_1, \ldots, b_d\right)^\top$, by partially differentiating the corresponding moment generating function
$$
\mathop{M_{\mathbf X}}\left(\mathbf t\right) = \frac{\left|2\pi\boldsymbol\Sigma\right|^{-1/2}}{\mathop{\mathbb P}\left(\mathbf a \leq \mathbf X \leq \mathbf b\right)} \int_{\mathbf a}^{\mathbf b} \exp\left(-\frac{1}{2} \left[\left(\mathbf x - \boldsymbol \mu\right)^\top {\boldsymbol \Sigma}^{-1} \left(\mathbf x - \boldsymbol \mu\right) - 2 \cdot \mathbf t^\top\mathbf x\right] \right) \mathrm d \mathbf x,
$$
where $\leq$ denotes component-wise inequality, $\mathbf t = \left(t_1, \ldots, t_d\right)^\top$, and $\boldsymbol \mu$ and $\boldsymbol \Sigma$ are the expected value and (non-singular) covariance matrix of the underlying untruncated $d$–variate normal random variable.
This yields

\begin{align}
\mathop{\mathbb E}\left(X_i\right) 
&= \frac{\partial \mathop{M_{\mathbf X}}\left(\mathbf t\right)}{\partial t_i}\bigg|_{\mathbf t = \mathbf 0} \\
&= \mu_i + \sum_{k=1}^d \sigma_{i,k} \left(\mathop{f_{X_k}}\left(a_k\right) - \mathop{f_{X_k}}\left(b_k\right)\right),
\end{align}

and

\begin{align} 
\mathop{\mathbb E}\left(X_iX_j\right) 
&= \frac{\partial^2 \mathop{M_{\mathbf X}}\left(\mathbf t\right)}{\partial t_i\partial t_j}\bigg|_{\mathbf t = \mathbf 0}\\
&= \sigma_{i,j} 
+ \sum_{k=1}^d \sigma_{i,k} \frac{\sigma_{j,k}\left(a_k\mathop{f_{X_k}}\left(a_k\right)-b_k\mathop{f_{X_k}}\left(b_k\right)\right)}{\sigma_{k,k}} \\
&\quad + \sum_{k=1}^d \sigma_{i,k} \sum_{q \neq k} \left(\sigma_{j, q} - \frac{\sigma_{k,q}\sigma_{j,k}}{\sigma_{k,k}}\right)\left[\left(\mathop{f_{X_k,X_q}}\left(a_k,a_q\right) - \mathop{f_{X_k,X_q}}\left(a_k,b_q\right)\right) \\
- \left(\mathop{f_{X_k,X_q}}\left(b_k,a_q\right) - \mathop{f_{X_k,X_q}}\left(b_k,b_q\right)\right)\right],
\end{align}
which also determines the entries the covariance matrix of $\mathbf X$ via $\mathop{\mathrm{Cov}}\left(X_i,X_j\right) = \mathop{\mathbb E}\left(X_iX_j\right) - \mathop{\mathbb E}\left(X_i\right) \mathop{\mathbb E}\left(X_j\right)$.

That reduces the problem to evaluating $\mathop{f_{X_k}}$ and $\mathop{f_{X_k,X_q}}$, the marginal density of $X_k$ and $\left(X_k,X_q\right)$, respectively, at specific points.
The former can be achieved with the algorithm given in [Cartinhour (1990)](https://doi.org/10.1080/03610929008830197). The latter turns out to be the product of $1/{\mathop{\mathbb P}\left(\mathbf a \leq \mathbf X \leq \mathbf b\right)}$, a bivariate normal density (evaluated at those points), and the multivariate normal probability obtained by integrating a $(d-2)$-variate normal density over a hyperrectangle.

For your problem

```r
library(TruncatedNormal)

set.seed(42)

n <- 500000
mu <- c(0, 0.5)
sigma <- matrix(c(1, 0.3, 0.3, 1), 2, 2)

lb <- c(-1, 0)
ub <- c( 1, 1)
X <- rtmvnorm(n, mu, sigma, lb, ub)
colMeans(X)
# [1] 0.0007696717 0.5002392194
cov(X)
#             [,1]        [,2]
# [1,] 0.287768996 0.007486595
# [2,] 0.007486595 0.080491050
```

their code gives

```r
# devtools::install_github("stefanwilhelm/tmvtnorm")
tmvtnorm::mtmvnorm(mean = mu, 
                   sigma = sigma, 
                   lower = lb, 
                   upper = ub)
# $tmean
# [1] 0.0 0.5
# 
# $tvar
#             [,1]        [,2]
# [1,] 0.287549082 0.007606965
# [2,] 0.007606965 0.080405828
```

---

**References**

- Cartinhour, J. (1990). [One-dimensional marginal density functions of a truncated multivariate normal density function](https://doi.org/10.1080/03610929008830197). *Communications in Statistics - Theory and Methods*, *19*(1), 197–203.
- Manjunath, B. G., & Wilhelm, S. (2021). [Moments calculation for the doubly truncated multivariate normal density](https://doi.org/10.35566/jbds/v1n1/p2). *Journal of Behavioral Data Science*, *1*(1), 13-33.

Comment: Short summary of the results presented in the paper would be useful to make the answer self-contained.

Comment: Many thanks for comments. I understand that the means and (co)variances will differ after truncation.

Comment: @Tim I hope my edit makes the answer sufficiently self-contained.